# Terraform Vault initialization Failed

Tags: hashicorp-vault

```
I am planning to install a terraform vault on a machine with the below confirguration error. I have edited the /etc/vault.d/vault.hcl

storage "file" { 
    path = "/vault/data" 
} 

listener "tcp" { 
    address = "127.0.0.1:8200" 
    tls_disable = 1 
} 

ui = true

Post which I tried to start the vault process using "systemctl start vault". It started no errors I can see. Then I initiated the "vault operator init", but got an error as below

Get "https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/seal-status": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client.

Any help on above I am using the centos machine.

Thanks

Raj
```

Tried to fix the errors and no luck, had updated the config files with the different set of parameters

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The default VAULT_ADDR is https://127.0.0.1:8200 but your Vault server is running with TLS disabled.

Run `export VAULT_ADDR=http://localhost:8200` before running `vault operator init` and you should have success.